# Django 1.9.1 - make migrations can't detect changes

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have Django 1.9.1 installed:

```
>>> django.__version__
'1.9.1'
```

And I had my model defined in main.models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Collection:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    desc = models.TextField()
    snap = models.ImageField()
    f = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name;
```

And I had already added "main" to INSTALLED_APPS in settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    ... # Other Django stuff
]
```

And when I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the following:

```
➜ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

I've searched through the internet and it seems like no one has encountered a problem like this... Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connection class needs to inherit from `models.Model`.